# Laravel, how can I remove file from dropify?

Tags: laravel, dropify

I'm using dropify for my project.

```
 <form action="{{route('ticket.update')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 @csrf
 <label>Ticket</label>
 <input type="file" name="ticket" class="dropify" data-max-file-size="5M"
 data-default-file="{{$foo->ticket ?? ''}}"
 data-allowed-file-extensions="pdf png jpg jpeg"/>
 <input type="submit" class="button"/>
 </form>
```

When I remove the image, also should be deleted from the database.
[image: remove-event]

> In Controller (After posting form with removed)

```
dd($request->ticket);
```

> Output

```
Null
```

Input even if its value already exists posted value is outputted as null.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do it for you....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropify').dropify(); //initializing dropify

  //Handling click event on Remove button of dropify
  $('.dropify-clear').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Remove Hit'); //Here you can manage you ajax request to delete 
                         //file from database.
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropify').dropify();
  
  $('.dropify-clear').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Remove Hit');
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Dropify/0.2.2/js/dropify.min.js" integrity="sha512-8QFTrG0oeOiyWo/VM9Y8kgxdlCryqhIxVeRpWSezdRRAvarxVtwLnGroJgnVW9/XBRduxO/z1GblzPrMQoeuew==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Dropify/0.2.2/css/dropify.css" integrity="sha512-In/+MILhf6UMDJU4ZhDL0R0fEpsp4D3Le23m6+ujDWXwl3whwpucJG1PEmI3B07nyJx+875ccs+yX2CqQJUxUw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<input type="file" class="dropify">
```

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to form.

```
<form action="{{route('ticket.update')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

[Read More About multipart/form-data](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_form_enctype.asp)

Comment: have edited my answer. You need to handle click event on Remove button, class of remove button is dropify-clear.

Comment: My earlier answer is rectifying your error in your file input code, where you must use enctype to handle file, otherwise you can not transport the file from html to your backend.